# Is there a way to wrap more than argument at once with Lodash's wrap

Tags: javascript, lodash

With _.wrap, is there a way to wrap multiple arguments at once, or another function that does it? Chaining _.wrap repeatedly seems bad as it stacks up function calls unnecessarily.

Example:

```
_.wrap(1, 2, _.add)() === 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

A close solution that comes to my mind is this:

```
_.wrap([1, 2], _.spread(_.add))() === 3;
```